# Checking thresholds and calculating the recovery time

Tags: excel, vba, time, recovery

This is what I would like to have happen:

```
Car ID  Sample point    Date        Viscosity    Output
123456  1               01/01/2016  400
123456  2               01/01/2016  100
123456  3               01/01/2016  100
123456  1               01/06/2016  100
123456  2               01/06/2016  80
123456  3               01/06/2016  90
123457  1               01/01/2017  600
123457  2               01/01/2017  800
123457  3               01/01/2017  900
123457  1               01/06/2017  200
123457  2               01/06/2017  100
123457  3               01/06/2017  50
```

Max. Viscosity Threshold 300
Normal Viscosity Level 200

I wish to check a viscosity recovery. It means I would like to first check Car ID, Sample point , Viscosity Value.

If Viscosity value is higher >300

I would like to check the next data set (same ID, Same sample point, next date) if for the same sample point viscosity came back to the normal value (<200) if not, proceed to the next date.

When Sample ID is finished, proceed to the next ID.

Later on for all data sets I wish to calculate the average recovery time.

**Example**:

```
Step 1
Car ID 123456 Sample 1 Date 01/01/2016 Viscosity 400 Above Threshold 

Step 2 'Checking for the Sample 1 next sampling if viscosity went  lower then Normal threshold

Row 4 Car ID 123456 Sample 1 Date 1/06/2016 Viscosity 100 Below Normal Threshold
```

> Output(recovery time): column 5:  5 months. End

```
Step 3 checking other sample point. If nothing finds, continue with the next car ID.
```

[Please find here picture with the actual spreadsheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqj6G.png)

Comment: Just trying to understand your query: if I understand your question correctly, you will first check row 1 (Car ID: 123456), then row 4 as its for the same Car ID and Sample point. Then move to row 7 as that's the new Car ID and so on. Is that what you are looking for? Also, when you say you want to **calculate the average recovery time**, what do you mean by **recovery time**? as there is no column in the sheet with **recovery time**

Comment: Please edit the question and post the expected output for provided sample.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Share your latest code attempt, and let us know where you are facing an error